# Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC debugger keeps quitting when I instantiate a new object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, asp.net-mvc-2

I being for the last 12 hours trying to understand why this is happening.

I am working in a ASP.NET MVC (C#) application where I created an abstract class that has base information for all the future models class.

Follow it's an example of code that I have done:

```
namespace TestingModelBind.Models.Home
{
    public abstract class Person 
    {
        public int PersonId {get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        private string _personValueHash;
        public string PersonValueHash
        {
            get { return //call function that get the Hash for the Person}
            set { _personValueHash= value; }
        }

        public abstract void GetPerson();

        internal abstract void SavePersonInformation();

        public void SetPerson()
        {
           if (_personValueHash!=PersonValueHash){SavePersonInformation();}
        }
    }
```

So I have a created an Abstract Class since the Implementation for GetPerson and SavePersonInformation depends on the Kind of individual. Here is the the code where I use the Abstract Class Person in a Worker Class

```
namespace TestingModelBind.Models.Home
{
    public class Worker: Person
    {
        public bool Consultant { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public override void GetPerson()
        {
            // Code to retrieve the Worker Information Based on the PersonId
        }
        internal override void SavePersonInformation()
        {
            // Code to Persist the Worker Information
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Controller where I use the Final Worker Class

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    Worker dataModel = new Worker(); // This is the line where the Debugger Crash
    if (id!=null)
    {
        dataModel.PersonId = (int) id;
        dataModel.GetPerson();
    }
    return View(dataModel);
}
```

Now the issue is that all the time that I try to instantiate the Worker Class the Debugger in Visual Studio crash giving me as an error this message:

> "The debugger cannot continue running
>   the process. Process was terminated."

I did keep a file from the IntelliTrace and when it gets to the moment of the crash I am getting this

> "No Source Available. No symbols are
>   loaded for any call stack frame. The
>   source code cannot be displayed.
>   Itellitrace time context: : Function
>   Entry:[Unknown Method]"

.

I am  going crazy on this, and is holding me back since in the real project.

Any Ideas? Thank You so much.

Comment: You probably have a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code that calculate the Hash for the Object. 
I am taking all the Properties values, creating a string and then Hashing the string (I am doing this to know if I really need to save the information or the user just browsed). 
The issue is that I was using Reflection for the looping on all the properties, and this will cause a problem when you do this piece of code and you are using some inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

When the Visual Studio debugger exits suddenly and the process in question terminates the problem is typically one of the following

- Memory corruption deep within the CLR
- Stack overflow

For your scenario I would say the Stack Overflow case is much more likely.  I would set a breakpoints in the methods you omitted and re-run the scenario.  If it is a stack overflow your should see your methods getting hit repeatedly and unendingly.

Comment: I did try that I commented the code inside those methods and on the PersonId I set up to give back all the time the same number. and it keeps crashing right when I try to instantiate the Worker class. Thank You so much for you idea.

Comment: @Giuseppe in the code in your post it looks like you're calling a `Worker` function vs. the worker constructor `new Worker`.  If that's not a typo have you put a breakpoint in the `Worker` function?

Comment: yes it's a Typo, it should say "new Worker();", I am thinking that the answer could be in the Memory corruption. I am in the middle to check if this will fail when it runs in another computer.

Comment: I try to execute the application on another machine, the problem still happening.
The only thing I noticed is that it takes a second maybe two after the instantiation for the Debugger to crash.

This is driving me nuts. at this moment I am not sure what to do.

Comment: @Giuseppe start setting breakpoints in your applications in places you don't suspect.  It's almost certainly a stack overflow problem and the best way to find it is to catch it in the act

Comment: Found the issue. It was in the Code that calculate the Hash for the Object. I am taking all the Properties values, creating a string and then Hashing the string (I am doing this to know if I really need to save the information or the user just browsed). The issue is that I was using Reflection for the looping on all the properties, and seems to be a problem when you do this piece of code and you are using some inheritance.